# Why B Tree complexity is O(log n), it is not a binary tree

Tags: time-complexity, b-tree

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/b-tree-set-1-introduction-2/) the search/insert/delete time complexity of a B Tree is O(log n). A B Tree can have > 2 children, i.e. it is not a binary tree. So I don't understand why it is log n -- shouldn't it be faster than log n? For example search should be worst case O(h) where h is the height of the tree.

Comment: Why would a three with 3 children not be *log(n)*?

Comment: from what i understand from the answers, it would be log n of a different base (base 3 in your example)

Comment: correct, but `loga(b)` is just `log(b)/log(a)`, hence that is a constant factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B-Tree is a generalization of Binary Tree where each node ***can*** have more than 2 children. But it is not certain. If for example, the number of children for each node was defined to be x, then the complexity would be [image: log_x n]. However, when the minimum number of children is 2 (as in Binary Tree) then the maximum height of tree will be [image: logn], and as mentioned in previous answer, Big-O considers the worst case scenario which is a tree with the largest height (log base 2). Therefore, the complexity of B-Tree is [image: O(logn)].

Comment: Equation is broken.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is not a binary tree. But if we perform binary serach algoritm inside a node (for the kyes inside a node) time complexity can be considered as O(logn).

let's consider,

degree of the B-tree (maximum number of children per node) ≤ m.
total number of nodes in the node : n

if the case is like above,

height of the tree is

```
O(logmn)   ----------(1)
```

since number of children can be changed per node, will have to do a logarithmic search per node order

```
(lgm)   ----------(2)
```

so total complexity for search in binary tree is

```
O(logmn) . O(lgm)   ----------(3)
```

according to the logarithmic operation ,

```
{logba = logca / logcb}
```

applying the above operation to (3)

```
O(logmn) . O(lgm) = O(lgn/lgm) . O(lgm)
                  = O(lgn)
```

so B tree time complexity for search operation is **O(lgn)**

Answer (score -1):

Big-O is a measure of *worst case complexity*; since B-tree nodes are not required to have more than 2 children, the worst case will be that *no* node has more than 2 children.